# Projecting GeoTIFF onto shaped roofs using CGA rules

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rule-based, cityengine, texture

I am working with CityEngine 2019.1 and would like to project a GeoTIFF as a texutre onto shaped roofs of 3D-buildings. Currently I am trying with the following code which essentials are described on https://doc.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/latest/cga/cga-setup-projection.htm:

```
solarMap = "data/Solarpotential_Buildings.tif"
attr FTYP = 0.0

const textureWidth = 1584.5 #Raster width in meters
const textureHeight = 1446.5  #Raster height in meters

offsetx = convert(x, scope, world, pos, 0, 0, 0) -
         (convert(x, scope, world, pos, 0, 0, 0) 
         % textureWidth)

offsetz = convert(z, scope, world, pos, 0, 0, 0) -
         (convert(z, scope, world, pos, 0, 0, 0) 
         % textureHeight)

Lot --> 

case FTYP == 2000.0 : color("#ffdddd") #Indicates the geometry is a wall
case FTYP == 3000.0 : Roof #FTYP = 3000 indicates the geometry is a roof
else : color("#aaaaff") #All other geometries

Roof -->

    # color, uv set 0
    setupProjection(0, world.xy, textureWidth, 
                   textureHeight, -offsetx, offsetz)
    # texture(solarMap)
    projectUV(0) #0 is used for colormaps so this should be correct
    scaleUV(0, 1, 1)
    set(material.colormap, solarMap)
```

I have tried lots of different variations within `setupProjection()` and `scaleUV()`, like `world.xz`, `world.yz`, etc. or without `offsets` or different `scaling factors`, but the GeoTIFF is always misaligned or distorted somehow. For example like this:

[image]

The colormap you can see below the buildings is the actual GeoTIFF added as plain texture for reference.

While doing it manually via `Shape texturing tool` and choosing `Projection` as `Mode`, the GeoTIFF is projected correctly.

[image]

[image]

All files as well as the scene do have the same CRS. Studying the linked help section and other related articles provided by ESRI didnt bring me any further so far. Basically, the error must be somewhere within this part of code:

```
setupProjection(0, world.xy, textureWidth, 
               textureHeight, -offsetx, offsetz)
projectUV(0)
scaleUV(0, 1, 1)
set(material.colormap, solarMap)
```

How can I achive this correctly projected result by using CGA rules?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me https://www.geoplanit.co.uk/?p=470 (actually the same code you have used)

Please, check your code, you set `world.xy`, but it should be `world.xz`, as it is in the code above

However I have an issue with a mapping while exporting from CE to slpk. The texture becomes misaligned. FBX gets it right though. I cut the solarmap with the footprints (each footprint generates a jpg texture with OBJECTID as base name). I calculated for each footprint its x_min and y_max in QGIS and its texture size. Then I have used the cga rule, when each building gets its own roof texture. It should work better, but in AGOL it became very blurry

```
/**
 * File:    simple_buildings.cga
 * Created: 3 Aug 2022 10:01:16 GMT
 * Author:  User
 */

version "2021.1"
# attributes below go from your footrpints
attr txtr_wdth = 79.000 #temp value
attr txtr_hght = 64.000 #temp value

attr map_posx = 321611.639 #temp value
attr map_posy = -4727970.216 #temp value
attr roof_txtr = "123" #temp value
attr Z_Min = 3
attr MEDIAN = 3
attr OBJECTID = 0


RoofTexture(nr)         = "/Default Project/images/" + nr + ".0.jpg"


@StartRule


Lot -->
    
    extrude(MEDIAN-Z_Min)
    comp(f) {side: Facade | top: Roof | bottom: Ground}
    

                           
Roof --> Rooftex
Rooftex --> 
    setupProjection(0, world.xz, txtr_wdth, txtr_hght)
    #texture(RoofTexture(OBJECTID)) 
    set(material.colormap, RoofTexture(OBJECTID))  
    projectUV(0) 
    translateUV(0, -map_posx/txtr_wdth, map_posy/txtr_hght) 
    scaleUV(0,1,-1)
    print (RoofTexture(OBJECTID))
    print(OBJECTID)

Facade -->
    color("#faeebb")
    /*split(y){ height   : Groundfloor | (height-1)*floorcount : Floor }*/
    
Ground-->
    color("#ffffff")

Floor -->
    color("#fffbe8")
```

Comment: Link-only answers are often deleted, because links fail over time. And it's not clear if this is an Answer or a new Question. Please [Edit] this post to summarize the linked doc and make clear how complete an Answer this is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).